# Identify files with 5 or more HTTPS URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a script that recursively searches a directory to find files which matches a regex 5 or more times.

Using the script I can search for files which look like

```
https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/1087
https://askubuntu.com/questions/758696/cannot-login-into-locked-ubuntu-14-04-session-unity
https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/14
https://www.huffpost.com/entry/our-shared-fears-and-how-_b_776720?guccounter=1
https://www.collaborativefund.com/blog/ideas-that-changed-my-life/
https://www.livescience.com/52882-charitable-acts-lead-to-bad-behavior.html
```

This has 5 or more lines that start with `https://`. If fewer than 5 lines start with `https://`, the file name will not be printed.

So far, what I came up with is:

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

for path in Path('/tmp/').rglob('*.adoc'):
    with open(path.resolve()) as file:
        count = 0
        for item in file:
            if re.match("^https://", item):
                count = count + 1
                if count > 4:
                    print(path.resolve())
                    break
```

The code has two loops and two conditions and it does not look right to me. How can I improve the code?

Comment: What I find "interesting" is that the function doing a recursive search is not itself recursive. Here is a recent question that is somewhat similar with useful tips: [Remove matching lines from all files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270544/219060). Besides, ask yourself is a regex is truly needed. It would be more economical to use `item.startswith`

Comment: If you really want a regex, then you might as well go all out: `if re.match('(^https://.*){5}','\n'.join(file.readlines()),re.MULTILINE): print(path.resolve())`.  That will probably be slower than `startswith`, but it may be easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so simple that there isn't much to improve.

In most cases you don't need a `resolve()` and should just omit this.

Use `count += 1` instead of `count = count + 1`.

If you're always going to be checking for a prefix, use `startswith` instead of a regular expression.

Use `path.open()` instead of `open(path)`.

### Suggested

Not tested.

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterator


def files_with_pat(directory: Path, glob: str, prefix: str, minimum_matches: int = 5) -> Iterator[Path]:
    for path in directory.rglob(glob):
        count = 0
        with path.open() as file:
            for line in file:
                if line.startswith(prefix):
                    count += 1
                    if count >= minimum_matches:
                        yield path
                        break


def test() -> None:
    for path in files_with_pat(
        directory=Path('/tmp'),
        glob='*.adoc',
        prefix='https://',
    ):
        print(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```